# Fast Interpolation / Resample of Numpy Array - Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

Currently, I have written some Python code that is inserted into a pipeline.

The incoming data comes in in a numpy array of shape (1,512,19,25). I use the `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom` to bring the array up to shape (1,512,38,50). This can be accomplished with one call to the function. Basically, it resizes each (19,25) piece to size (38,50).

Later in the code, when the data is moving the other way, different data is again resized the in the other direction (38,50) to (19,25).

Everything works as implemented, however I am finding that this is really slow. For example, I tested the `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom` function to resize an image file and it was way slower than Matlab's `imresize` function.

What are faster ways to do this in Python?

Comment: What sort of interpolation are you using with `ndimage.zoom` (i.e. what is the `order` parameter)? Is it just nearest-neighbour or are you using linear, bicubic etc.?

Comment: the default. i have not changed it, so i assume order 3.

Comment: Bicubic interpolation is intrinsically quite expensive. Could you get away with using bilinear or nearest-neighbour interpolation instead?

Comment: Yes, but is that achieved by changing the order parameter? Isn't it still doing spline interpolation? Is there some other function I should use that would be faster?

Comment: `order=0` will give you nearest-neighbour, `order=1` will give you bilinear etc. I would expect either of these to be quite a lot faster than `order=3`, but there may also be faster methods. I was mainly asking whether or not nearest-neighbour or bilinear would be suitable for your needs. BTW, I suggest you edit the title of your question - what you're doing is not simply resizing or repeating your array, but rather resampling or interpolating it.

Comment: What is order=2 then if order=1 is bilinear? I agree that changing the order may be helpful.

Comment: `order=2` would be quadratic interpolation, which is rarely used in practice

Comment: Could you please post a *simplest possible* example code?  I anticipate that this will include the array create and zoom calls, with the zoom parameters that you want to use.   I would like to answer you question using that exact code.

Comment: @ali_m Where'd you get that info? I can't find a page of scipy describing the order... Like for citing and so on... (i know this question is seven years old xD)

Answer (score 7):

**TLDR;** Check out Skimage's [pyramid_gaussian](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/transform/plot_pyramid.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-transform-plot-pyramid-py). On a single image of (512, 512) it shows an order of 0.3M times speed-up. (163 ms/471 ns = 346072). [Pillow-SIMD](https://github.com/uploadcare/pillow-simd) does [super-fast](https://python-pillow.org/pillow-perf/) resamples/resize but requires you to uninstall PIL, Pillow before you install it. It uses parallel processing (single instruction, multiple data - SIMD) and better algorithms such as replacing a convolution-based Gaussian blur with a sequential-box one. Advice to use this for production environments after setting up a separate `venv`.

---

There are multiple ways of upsampling and downsampling your image. I will add some benchmarks of the methods that I have worked with. I will keep updating this answer as I come across more methods so that this can act as a reference for others on SO.

```
#Utility function for plotting original, upsampled, and downsampled image

def plotit(img, up, down):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(10,15))
    axes[0].imshow(img)
    axes[1].imshow(up)
    axes[2].imshow(down)
    axes[0].title.set_text('Original')
    axes[1].title.set_text('Upsample')
    axes[2].title.set_text('Downsample')
```

IIUC, this is somewhat your pipeline -

```
from scipy.ndimage import zoom
from skimage.data import camera

img = camera() #(512,512)
up = zoom(img,2) #upsample image

#some code
...

down = zoom(up,0.5) #downsample the upsampled image

plotit(img, up, down)
```

[image]

---

**Methods & Benchmarks**
`(in no specific order)`

*1. Scipy [zoom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html) (order=3)*

The array is zoomed using spline interpolation of a given order, in this case, the default is order = 3.

```
%%timeit
#from scipy.ndimage import zoom
up = zoom(img,2)
down = zoom(up,0.5)

#163 ms ± 12.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

*2. Scipy [zoom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html) (order=0)*

The array is zoomed using spline interpolation of a given order, in this case, order = 0.

```
%%timeit
#from scipy.ndimage import zoom
up = zoom(img,2, order=0)
down = zoom(up,0.5, order=0)

#18.7 ms ± 950 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*3. Skimage [pyramid_gaussian](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.7.0/api/skimage.transform.pyramids.html#skimage.transform.pyramids.pyramid_gaussian)*

In a Gaussian pyramid, subsequent images are weighted down using a Gaussian average (Gaussian blur) and scaled-down. Applying a Gaussian blur to an image is the same as convolving the image with a Gaussian function. The amount of blur depends on the standard deviation size (sigma).

```
%%timeit
#from skimage.transform import import pyramid_gaussian
up = pyramid_gaussian(img,2)
down = pyramid_gaussian(up,0.5)

#471 ns ± 30.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

*4. Skimage [pyramid_expand](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.7.0/api/skimage.transform.pyramids.html#skimage.transform.pyramids.pyramid_expand) and [pyramid_reduce](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.7.0/api/skimage.transform.pyramids.html#skimage.transform.pyramids.pyramid_reduce)*

An image pyramid is a type of multi-scale image representation in which an image is subject to repeated smoothing and subsampling. The first function smooths and then upsamples the image, while the second does the same but instead downsamples, both of these use spline order=1 by default.

```
%%timeit
#from skimage.transform import import pyramid_expand, pyramid_reduce
up = pyramid_expand(img,2)
down = pyramid_reduce(up,2)

#120 ms ± 3.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

*5. Skimage [rescale](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.rescale)*

Scales an image by a certain factor. Performs spline interpolation (order=1 by default) to up-scale or down-scale N-dimensional images. Note that anti-aliasing should be enabled when down-sizing images to avoid aliasing artifacts.

```
%%timeit
#from skimage.transform import import rescale
up = rescale(img,2)
down = rescale(up,0.5)

#83 ms ± 3.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

*6. PIL [resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) with Nearest pixel [filter](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-filters) for resampling*

Returns a resized copy of this image. Picks one nearest pixel from the input image. Ignores all other input pixels.

```
%%timeit
#from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(img)
up = im.resize((im.width*2, im.height*2),resample=Image.NEAREST)
down = up.resize((up.width//2, up.height//2),resample=Image.NEAREST)

#704 µs ± 29.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

*7. PIL [resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) with BILINEAR [filter](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-filters) for resampling*

Returns a resized copy of this image. For resize calculates the output pixel value using linear interpolation on all pixels that may contribute to the output value. For other transformations, linear interpolation over a 2x2 environment in the input image is used.

```
%%timeit
#from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(img)
up = im.resize((im.width*2, im.height*2),resample=Image.BILINEAR)
down = up.resize((up.width//2, up.height//2),resample=Image.BILINEAR)

#10.2 ms ± 877 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*8. PIL [resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) with BICUBIC [filter](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-filters) for resampling*

Returns a resized copy of this image. For resize calculates the output pixel value using cubic interpolation on all pixels that may contribute to the output value. For other transformations cubic interpolation over a 4x4 environment in the input image is used.

```
%%timeit
#from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(img)
up = im.resize((im.width*2, im.height*2),resample=Image.BICUBIC)
down = up.resize((up.width//2, up.height//2),resample=Image.BICUBIC)

#12.3 ms ± 326 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*9. PIL [resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) with Lanczos [filter](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-filters) for resampling*

Returns a resized copy of this image. Calculates the output pixel value using a high-quality Lanczos filter (a truncated sinc) on all pixels that may contribute to the output value.

```
%%timeit
#from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(img)
up = im.resize((im.width*2, im.height*2),resample=Image.LANCZOS)
down = up.resize((up.width//2, up.height//2),resample=Image.LANCZOS)

#15.7 ms ± 184 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Have you actually checked the result? `pyramid_gaussian` returns just a generator, not the rescaled image. You need to actually iterate that generator to really get the rescaled image. Then I get similar speed as Scipy zoom order=0.

Answer (score 0):

Check the benchmarks in https://python-pillow.org/pillow-perf/

TL;DR: for most scenarios the fastest way in Python is using [pillow-simd](https://github.com/uploadcare/pillow-simd).