# Multi Scale Segmentation mask outputs in keras in U Net

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras

So this is the model, with input as a single image and outputs at different scales of the image, i.e., I, 1/2 I, 1/4 I and 1/8 I, `Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[out6, out7, out8, out9])`

I am not sure how to create the train dataset. Suppose the input to the y_train will be data of say shape (50, 192, 256, 3) where 3 = channel of the image, 192 is the width and 256 is the height, and there are 50 of them, but how to create a y_train which will have 4 components? I have tried with zip and then converting it to numpy but that doesn't works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you necessarily want the model to learn to generate multi-scale masks then you can try downsampling to generate the scaled masks for supervised learning using UNET. You can use interpolation-based methods to automatically resize an image with minimum loss. [Here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381551/fast-interpolation-resample-of-numpy-array-python/65322167#65322167) where I compare benchmarks against multiple such methods.

If you want to create `[masks, masks_half, masks_quarter, masks_eighth]` for your `model.fit`, which is the list of original + rescaled versions of the mask images, you may wanna try a fast downsampling method (depending on the size of your dataset).

Here I have used `skimage.transform.pyramid_reduce` to downsample a mask to half, quarter, and eighth of its scale. The method uses interpolation (spline), but can be controlled via parameters. Check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwEIN.png) for more details.

```
from skimage.transform import pyramid_reduce

masks = np.random.random((50, 192, 256, 3))

masks_half = np.stack([pyramid_reduce(i, 2, multichannel=True) for i in masks])
masks_quater = np.stack([pyramid_reduce(i, 4, multichannel=True) for i in masks])
masks_eighth = np.stack([pyramid_reduce(i, 8, multichannel=True) for i in masks])

print('Shape of original',masks.shape)
print('Shape of half scaled',masks_half.shape)
print('Shape of quater scaled',masks_quater.shape)
print('Shape of eighth scaled',masks_eighth.shape)
```

```
Shape of original (50, 192, 256, 3)
Shape of half scaled (50, 96, 128, 3)
Shape of quater scaled (50, 48, 64, 3)
Shape of eighth scaled (50, 24, 32, 3)
```

---

Testing on a single image/mask -

```
from skimage.data import camera
from skimage.transform import pyramid_reduce

def plotit(img, h, q, e):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,4, figsize=(10,15))
    axes[0].imshow(img)
    axes[1].imshow(h)
    axes[2].imshow(q)
    axes[3].imshow(e)
    axes[0].title.set_text('Original')
    axes[1].title.set_text('Half')
    axes[2].title.set_text('Quarter')
    axes[3].title.set_text('Eighth')

img = camera() #(512,512)
h = pyramid_reduce(img, 2)   #Half
q = pyramid_reduce(img, 4)   #Quarter
e = pyramid_reduce(img, 8)   #Eighth

plotit(img, h, q, e)
```

[image]

*Notice the change in scale over x and y-axis* --------------------->

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but you misunderstood my question. I wanted to create y_train at multi scale. Suppose we have an image, which is segmentation mask of size say 192x256x1 (i.e., grayscale), now I want to pass some object to the output mask of the model which will have all the 4 scales of the image. I am unsure how to do that, i.e., how to pass that mask stuff at multiscale into the model.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to pass a single scale mask to the model, then it will be a tensor object of size 40x192x256x1 where 40 are the number of images I am creating for y_train, but I am not sure how to create a bunch of multi scale y_train and pass them at the same time. Will it be like passing 4 separate list of numpy array to the model or will it be something like zip object of numpy array...

Comment: Do you have your segmentation mask at the original size? If yes, then its an image, and you can just pass it via a pyramid_reduce to create the other 3 outputs for your model to train on.. as I have suggested above.

Comment: Yes, I have the segmentation mask at original size, and just want to do incremental reconstruction of segmentationn mask via U-Net

Comment: Yes my friend, check the part of the answer where I generate images_half, images_quarter and images_eighth

Comment: You can take your tensor with segmentation masks (images) at original size and create 3 other output tensors. Then use these as your multi-scale segmentation mask to train your model. Each has a batch dimension of 50

Comment: So will it be 4 lists of tensors?

Comment: No its not a list of tensor, check the shape of the outputs. `(batch_size, height, width, channels)`. each of them is a batch_size of 50, as original. while their height and width are halved (downsampled) with same number of channels.

Comment: So your model becomes `Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[out6, out7, out8, out9])` and while fitting you provide `model.fit([X_train], [mask, mask_half, mask_quarter, mask_eighth])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228451/discussion-between-akshay-sehgal-and-jimut123).

Comment: Do you have a sample code for this, like you could point to some external source which does this... it will be helpful. MNET [https://github.com/HzFu/MNet_DeepCDR/blob/master/mnet_deep_cdr/Model_MNet.py](https://github.com/HzFu/MNet_DeepCDR/blob/master/mnet_deep_cdr/Model_MNet.py) does that but it is not exactly what  I want. It will be very helpful if you could point to the data generator..

Comment: Ok... Thanks a lot m8!